# Dipole antenna circuit diagram

Tags: rf, filter, radio

I have this circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzdnlQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to build a radio and I need to build a band pass filter . How do I do that?

Comment: What has this got to do with a dipole antenna (mentioned in your title) and, what has the schematic you posted got to do with band-pass filtering?

Comment: Hi! Um, this schematic is missing more than a bandbass filter to make it a radio; not quite sure how to help you there – the kind of filter design you'd need depends on the architecture of your radio and the frequencies you're operating on. Sadly, this is not a working radio architecture, so, nothing useful can be said.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on the type of radio you are trying to build?

Comment: I don't know the types of the radio but I know how information travels through electromagnetic waves and induction of current .Just building random circuits to see if I can pick up something from my local radio station.

Comment: "Random circuit" approach requires *incredible* patience. As Marcus has pointed out, this circuit fails because it contains only linear components: you're missing an important fundamental concept of radio circuits. A less-frustrating approach: start with a simple circuit that works, and judge what modifications *enhance* or *diminish* audio out.

Comment: yep, McCarter, that's not how things work out: when designing anything, you start with a mental theory of how it should work, and then use the components necessary. However, if your theory is too vague, or too far from reality, your design runs off into the blue and you'll not ever build something useful. This is exactly what's the case with the schematic you posted here: yes, you need a speaker and an antenna. That's the only thing for sure. But the rest of your circuitry, including the annotation that your speaker has 1Ω impedance, is just not going to get you a receiver.

Answer (score 1):

If we read the question as it is we can state that you want to build 2 things:

thing 1 = a radio

thing 2 = a bandpass filter

In addition you have a circuit which is drawn in the question, but you obviously have no problems with it. Otherwise they would be written in the question. We do not know what your circuit is wanted to do. It has an antenna so it can catch some radiowaves and create some voltage, probably far less than 1V to the speaker. But it's not a radio receiver because there's nothing done to extract the low frequency audio signal from the radio frequency signal possibly picked by the antenna.

Building radios, both transmitters and receivers have been a popular hobby far longer than 100 years. I do not recommend building transmitters because generally transmitting needs a license, only few narrow frequency bands are free for hobbyists and even then there are strict by law enforced rules how one should do his transmitting.

Radio receivers can be constructed more freely. As long as you obey the construction codes of electric devices and your devices do not transmit anything beyond the allowed stray radiation levels there should be no problems.

It's easiest to build a crystal receiver. It's useful if there's an AM broadcasting station somewhere near enough, for ex. in the same town. Do some web searches for crystal receivers and other, more sensitive radio receiver schematics. Get a book for radio building hobbyists.

Forget the bandpass filter until you have a plan to build some device which needs it as a functional block. Radio receivers are good example which benefit by having one to separate radio stations which have different frequencies. More complex receivers than the crystal receiver need several of them.

Comment: the transformer is used to extract the signal from the antenna

Comment: the transformer can give an output only due some non-idealities because the other end of the primary is not connected. The extracted signal is a weak copy of what's feeded to the antenna in the radio station. But it can still have a substantial voltage if the transmitter is your neighbour. All parts which extract the speech and music from the extracted radio signal are missing. The radio signal is at far too high frequency to be able to produce anything hearable in the speaker.

Comment: Oops I didn't see the this answer before I posted mine. Good overview.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for a Crystal radio, since it is based on a band pass filter, and a non-linear element.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio

It is also an active discussion topic in this forum. Search for "Crystal radio" in the search bar at the top of this page.

If you like the simplicity, and want to get started, you can buy a kit or a ready made one, and open it up. They are very elegant designs. Then improve your knowledge from there.